# How do I delete a row via clicking an image from a column on the same row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

How do i delete a row via clicking an image from a column on the same row?

This is the code for adding a row

```
function addrow() {
    var table = document.getElementById("tablelist");
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cells = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        cells[i] = row.insertCell(i);
        cells[i].innerHTML = "New";
    }
    cells[6] = row.insertCell(6);
    cells[6].innerHTML = '<img id="pencil" src="images/pencil-black.png"></img><img id="lock" src="images/lock-black.png"></img><img id="bin" src="images/bin-black.png"></img>';
}
```

This is my jquery code but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".userbox").on({
        mouseenter : function() {
            $(this).find('img').each(function() {
                $(this)
                .attr(
                    'src',
                    $(this).attr('src').replace('-black.png',
                                                '-white.png'));
            });
        },
        mouseleave : function() {
            $(this).find('img').each(function() {
                $(this)
                .attr(
                    'src',
                    $(this).attr('src').replace('-white.png',
                                                '-black.png'));
            });
        }
    }, 'tr');

    $("tr").on('tr', '.bin', function() {
        $(this).slideUp();
    });

});
```

Note: I am aware that `.slideUp()` isn't deleting a row.

Comment: Why are you not using a selector per row? Like: $(".userbox tr")

Comment: $(this). will give the current element!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

id must be unique in a document, so you need to change it to a class attribute

Then you need to use delegated event registration

```
$('#tablelist').on('click', '.bin', function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').slideUp();
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r5BN2/)

Comment: this might be a stupid question by how do i change an `img id` to an `img class`

Comment: @LiewJiaJun a more jquery-ish approach to `addrow` can be http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r5BN2/2/

Comment: Also `slideup` doesn't really work in a row, you can easily swap it with hide

Answer (score 1):

```
$('table').on('click', 'img', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

ps the `slideUp()` animation doesn't work on `tr` elements